# Part of this bucket may contain partial data - kibana Issue

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, bigdata

I am facing problem while visualizing graph over kibana as its not displaying all the items from my bucket and giving warning as below

```
Part of this bucket may contain partial data.
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiHq4.png) is screen shot for same. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Kindly help to get it resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You've asked Kibana to use "years" as the x-axis.  Since 2016 isn't done yet, any data for 1/1-now would be in the "2016" bucket, but it's "not complete".  Make sense?

Comment: ys it does about warning. But what about data incompleteness .while i am splinting bars there should be 6 split but its showing only 4  . If i change the order by clause in my split bar i can see others too but not all of them together. Any Idea ???

Comment: The information you provided in your original question doesn't say anything about 4 bars vs. 6, so I really can't address that.  Doesn't sound related to this issue on the surface.