# Visualization tool to use with elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am unable to full fill my client visualization  requirements through Kibana as it have some limitation.Could any one please suggest any better open source tool other than Kibana to use with elastic.

Comment: Maybe you should enumerate some of the requirements you have that Kibana doesn't support?

Comment: @val Kindly have a look on these three question which will give you a fair idea ,what exactly i m looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35764519/kibana-filter-data-on-the-basis-of-one-field-and-then-grouping-values-on-basis      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745552/part-of-this-bucket-may-contain-partial-data-kibana-issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745552/part-of-this-bucket-may-contain-partial-data-kibana-issue   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721949/dash-board-creation-on-kibana-from-different-indexes